# Unable to check whether JWT token is available for each route in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, routes, jwt

I have a node application.When customer routes to ('/login') and on valid credentials I am generating JWT token with some expiry time and routes to next page. And if user tries to access any route eg:('/home') directly after login ,if token is not expired he should be able to route directly. If token is expired I need to route to ('/login').

But currently it is working partially, if token is available he is directly able to route to ('/home). But when I open the same route in completely different browser/incognito window he is still able to route and it is taking the previous token. Which should not be and he should be routed to ('/login'). How can we do this scenario.

Below is my code which I tried

```
const SECRET = 'server secret';
var token;
router.post('/auth', passport.authenticate(  
  'local', {
   session: false
  }),generateToken, inserttoken,respond);
function generateToken(req, res, next) {  
   token = jwt.sign({
   id: req.user.id,
   },SECRET, {
    expiresIn: 60
  });
   req.token = token;
   next();
 }
 //In inserttoken() Iam inserting token value in db.
 router.get('/home', function(req, res){
    jwt.verify(token, 'server secret', function(err, decoded) {
      if (err) {
        console.log("token expired");
        res.redirect('/');
      } 
      else{
        res.render('index.html');
      } 
   });
});
```

Any help appreciated.Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

That is the intended behaviour. Think of the JWT as a key and your REST API as lock. When someone comes with a key to open the lock, the lock will only check the key, whether the key is correct or not. But the lock will not check whether the person carrying that key is correct person.

That's what happens here as well. JWT is just a key. It does not convey information to the REST API about client (browser in your case) that is sending requests with that key. REST API just checks the key and allows/denies the request.

(This answer is based on the assumption that you are sending the same key you obtained from the previous browser in your incognito mode browser as well)